# tns build android 《app-debug.apk》package too big

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

my project code size only 2M ,but by command: [tns build android ] create 《app-debug.apk》 size 78M.

nativescript-vue project

Answer (score 0):

NaticeScript adds node_modules dependencies in build and that's the reason for increased size of android and ios app.If you want smaller size you can opt for native android/ios app.

Comment: FYI, I still use Angular and my project size is around 8mb (including all assets) but my package size is roughly 20mb. It could be some minor issue with build flow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use release version of APK and not the debug one.
2. Try a clean build, sometimes the node_modules folder is copied as it's by mistake (not exactly sure why / when it happens), a clean build mostly resolves the issue.